# Powershell: How to get specific properties from users in a OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get some information for an audit. here's the code that i used but the output is empty except for the name. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
$ou = Get-ADGroup -Identity Administrators -Properties member
$user = Get-ADGroupmember -Identity $ou 
    foreach ($user in $ou){
    Get-ADGroupmember -Identity Administrators | Select-Object name, lastlogondate,passwordlastset
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators -recursive | select samaccountname

foreach ($user in $members){
Get-ADUser -Identity  $user.samaccountname -Properties name, lastlogondate,passwordlastset| Select-Object name, lastlogondate,passwordlastset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the properties lastlogondate and passwordlastset are not returned, you have to specify those (or all by using a *) using the -properties argument

```
Get-ADGroupmember -Identity Administrators -properties name,lastlogondate,passwordlastset | Select-Object name, lastlogondate,passwordlastset
```

or

```
Get-ADGroupmember -Identity Administrators -properties * | Select-Object name, lastlogondate,passwordlastset
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the response "Get-ADGroupMember : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'properties'." It looks like i cannot get the properties from a group.